# C# - data.table: split single column to multiple columns

Tags: c#, split

How can I split a single column to multiple columns in c#?

For example:
I have a table with a single column that looks like this:

```
Acceleration100
From 2010-01-04 To 2015-06-03
From 2015-06-22 To 2015-06-23
Acceleration20
From 2010-01-14 To 2015-08-03
From 2015-09-22 To 2015-12-23
Acceleration200
From 2010-11-04 To 2015-06-13
From 2015-02-22 To 2015-06-29
```

I want it to look like this:

```
Acceleration100                | Acceleration20                | Acceleration200
From 2010-01-04 To 2015-06-03  | From 2010-01-14 To 2015-08-03 | From 2010-11-04 To 2015-06-13
From 2015-06-22 To 2015-06-23  | From 2015-09-22 To 2015-12-23 | From 2015-02-22 To 2015-06-29
```

What should I do?

Comment: This does not make sense. How your data are represented in C#? Please provide a clearer picture.

Comment: With no specific data structure? From one display to an other without going to real date time type or anything?

Comment: `What should I do?` First, you should try to come up with a solution on your own. If you get stuck, come back here, show us the code you have written, and then we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a real data structure like `Dictionary<string, List<string>>` where the key is the `Acceleration XYZ`. The parse your file lines by lines. If you encounter a line with `Acceleration100` you insert it as a key then all following value will be added to the list.

This way you may have multiple occurrences of `Acceleration100` under the same key.

You might want to change `List<string>` to a more robust structure 
with DateTime properties: StartDate, EndDate. Perhaps even check if the "From To" line is in the correct format.

Then the projection to column can be done like: [C#: Bind Dictionary<string, List<string>> to DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48962858/c-bind-dictionarystring-liststring-to-datatable/48963099)

Then you can format the output like :[Print Contents Of A DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15547959/print-contents-of-a-datatable)